# Test the number of emails enqueued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-activejob

We can check `enqueued_jobs.length`, provided that email is the only possible type of background job.

```
it 'sends exactly one, particular email' do
  expect { post :create }.to(
    # First, we can check about the particular email we care about.
    have_enqueued_mail(MyMailer, :my_particular_email)
  )

  # But we also have to check that no other email was sent.
  expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.length).to eq(1)
end
```

Is there a better way to assert that:

1. `MyMailer.my_particular_email` was enqueued,
2. no other email was enqueued,
3. and we don't care if other, non-email background jobs were enqueued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
# first filter MyMailer job 
my_mail_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.select { |job|
  job[:job] == SendEmailsJob &&
  job[:args][0] == "MyMailer"
}
# check only once
expect(my_mail_jobs.length).to eq(1) 
# and that send to your particular email not other email
expect(my_mail_jobs.first[:args]).to include("your particular email")
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been experimenting with something very similar, directly inspecting `enqueued_jobs` as you do. It's awkward, but it's the only solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 5):

I believe [`once`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers/BuiltIn/CountExpectation#once-instance_method) will work with this matcher.

```
expect {
  post :create
}.to have_enqueued_mail(MyMailer, :my_particular_email).once
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right that `once` will work, but I also want to assert that no other mail was enqueued.

Comment: @JaredBeck I don't see anything in RSpec. There's [`assert_enqueued_emails(1) { post :create }`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/TestHelper.html#method-i-assert_enqueued_emails) which is just a wrapper that looks for queued mailed jobs. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/test_helper.rb#L155

Comment: @JaredBeck That's always tricky proving that something is not happening, and you always have to draw the line when asserting what should not happen, That being said, I can't see why  `.not_to have_enqueued_mail(MyMailer, :this_should_not_have_beeen_sent)` would not work...